# gedit color-highlighted text does not print

Tags: printing, colors, gedit

I am having a problem getting gedit to print color-highlighted C code. It prints in monochrome instead. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and the printer is an Epson WF-3520. The printer prints web, photos, etc. in color OK. I have the same symptom when printing a Python (.py) file. If I print to a file (foo.c.pdf), the .pdf file displays and prints in monochrome. When I print to the printer and check the GNOME Print Color menu, is shows: Printer Profile: Unspecified profile. Since I see the problem when I print to a file, I suspect the problem is not in GNOME Print, though -- but in gedit. My gedit version is 3.10.4. By the way, vim color-prints the file using command :hardcopy, but conditionals (if,then,etc.) are in yellow (can't see them on white!). A better choice: enscript -E --color foo.c. Any ideas on gedit? Thanks.